# SQLite cascading increment, maintain uniqueness (for ordered list)

Tags: sqlite

I would like to move entries to the middle of an ordered list where the order is maintained by the unique column "orderby". When moving values to the middle of a list I specify the orderby value and if the value is already taken, then the orderby of the old row should be incremented or decremented by one, depending on the direction of the movement.

For testing purposes I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
orderby integer,
UNIQUE(orderby) )
```

And I currently have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [test_insert] 
BEFORE UPDATE OF [orderby]  
ON [test] 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

UPDATE test
SET orderby = orderby + 1
WHERE NEW.orderby = orderby;

END
```

However, this only works if the orderby value created by the trigger is unused.

ie if  I run `UPDATE test SET orderby = 2 WHERE orderby = 1`, it will work with a table that has orderby values {1; 2}, but not with a table that has values {1; 2; 3}

How can I solve this? Or perhaps do it completely differently?

EDIT: If I cannot get this to work I guess I always have the option of incrementing all orderby-s in a range, however, I would still like to get this to work, which would allow me to use gaps in the values or orderby and gain more efficieny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: replaced original answer now that desire is clarified.

You can't define the field as unique because even the BEFORE trigger fires after the uniqueness violation. Therefore, use AFTER which is safer.

Here's the code I think you want followed by a few test updates.

```
CREATE TABLE test(pk char primary key,
                  orderby integer);

CREATE TRIGGER test_insert 
  AFTER UPDATE OF orderby ON test 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE test
       set orderby = orderby + 1
     where test.orderby >= NEW.orderby
       and test.pk != NEW.pk;
  END;

insert into test (pk, orderby) values ("a", 1);
insert into test (pk, orderby) values ("b", 2);
insert into test (pk, orderby) values ("c", 3);

select * from test;

update test set orderby=1 where pk='c';
select * from test order by orderby";
update test set orderby=2 where pk='b';
select * from test order by orderby;
update test set orderby=4 where pk='a';
select * from test order by orderby;
```

Comment: Hmm I just read your EDIT and am confused if I gave the right answer or not, as it sounds like you only want to edit one row, even though adding 1 to the prior row could still make orderby not unique.

Comment: Actually, new entries would always be at the end of the list (and they orderby value would be the highest orderby + 1), but I need to be able to reorder the list and thats where I start having problems with having unique orderby values. Slightly edited, your answer would be the same as incrementing all orderby-s in a range and it would indeed work and if you think it is more efficient I will use it. 
PS I will make my question more clear